# JBoss DataSource configuration Issue

Tags: java, servlets, jboss, oracle10g, jndi

I am unable to configure datasource in jBoss. Following is configuration in **jboss web.xml**

```
<jboss-web>  
<resource-ref>  
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/testDataSource</res-ref-name> <!-- matches web.xml -->  
    <jndi-name>java:jdbc/testDataSource</jndi-name> <!-- matches oracle-ds.xml -->  
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>  
</resource-ref>  
</jboss-web>
```

We have created **oracle-ds.xml** which contains:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<datasources>  
  <local-tx-datasource>  
    <jndi-name>jdbc/testDataSource</jndi-name>  
    <connection-url>jdbc:oracle:thin:@11.120.184.77:1521:starsdev</connection-url>  
    <driver-class>oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</driver-class>  
    <user-name>cmsusr</user-name>  
    <password>cmsusr</password>  
    <min-pool-size>2</min-pool-size>  
    <max-pool-size>20</max-pool-size>  
    <idle-timeout-minutes>5</idle-timeout-minutes>  
    <track-statements/>  
    <metadata>  
      <type-mapping>Oracle10g</type-mapping>  
    </metadata>  
  </local-tx-datasource>  
</datasources>
```

I have created one servlet which contains following code in service method:

```
Context initialContext = new InitialContext();  
Context envContext = (Context) initialContext.lookup( "java:comp/env" );  
DataSource ds = (DataSource) envContext.lookup( "jdbc/testDataSource" );
PrintWriter pw = response.getWriter();
pw.print(ds);
```

When I'm running my servlet it is showing following error:

[STDOUT] **javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: jdbc not bound**

Comment: Which version of JBoss AS are you running?

Comment: Try to add `<use-java-context>false</use-java-context>` to oracle-ds.xml.

Comment: @user3757014 we are using jBoss version 4

Comment: @cy3er I have inserted mentioned line below metadata tag as:
....
<metadata> <type-mapping>Oracle10g</type-mapping></metadata>
<use-java-context>false</use-java-context>

**Still facing same error**

Answer (score 0):

Do it in a single lookup.  There's no need to use two Contexts here.

```
 Context initialContext = new InitialContext(); 
 DataSource ds = (DataSource) initialContext.lookup("java:comp/env/jdbc/testDataSource");
```

Comment: I have tried this also and getting **datasource object null** error

Comment: <driver-class>oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver</driver-class>
Where have you mapped <resource-root path="ojdbc6.jar"/> ??